# Error in running Kms-opencv-plugin sample

Tags: kurento

**What i do:**

1.I installed Kurento media server in my machine using the link
    http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installation_guide.html

2.After start the server,i run the hello world sample using the link
https://www.kurento.org/docs/6.0.0/tutorials/js/tutorial-1-helloworld.html

3.It run well for that example,

**What i have to do:**

**case1:**

Now i need to run the opencv sample in kurento

1.I downloaded the **kms-opencv-plugin-sample** from the link
   https://github.com/Kurento/kms-opencv-plugin-sample

2.When i run the cmakelist in the folder in **cmake-gui**,it asked for the dependancies

3.I downloaded the **kms-core** from the link
https://github.com/Kurento/kms-core and installed it

4.Also downloaded the **kms-cmake-util**
https://github.com/Kurento/kms-cmake-utils

Now i build kms-opencv-plugin-sample using the cmake,it shows the following error

```
     Error calling code generator: 
     CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CodeGenerator.cmake:80 
          (message):
    Output error: Exception in thread "main"
   org.kurento.modulecreator.KurentoModuleCreatorException: Import 'core' with
   version ^5.0.0 not found in dependencies, found version: 6.4.0

at
          org.kurento.modulecreator.definition.ModuleDefinition.resolveImports(ModuleDefinition.java:372)
```

**Case 2:**

1.I also tried to build using the command

```
    debuild -us -uc -d
```

From the command prompt

2.Also install the dependancies

```
    kms-core-dev 
    kms-elements-dev
    kms-filters-dev
```

3.It shows the error

```
   dpkg-buildpackage: warning: build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied;    aborting
   dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)
   debuild: fatal error at line 1364:
   dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
```

What i have to do to solve this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Case 1:**

The problem is that this example project is outdated and is requesting for kms-core 5.0.0. It should be updated soon.

You can update it yourself by changing kurentoVersion in [this file](https://github.com/Kurento/kms-opencv-plugin-sample/blob/master/src/server/interface/opencvpluginsample.kmd.json). Try "^6.4.0", that is the last released version.

**Case 2:**

This case fails because the dependencies in `debian/control` are for kurento version 5 that become incompatible with version 6 dependencies. As in your first case you installed latest versions of the project (took from git), you have a mix of version between installed packages (for the version 5) and manually installed projects in version 6.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @santoscadenas.
case 1:
   I updated the version to 6.4.0 in **/src/server/interface/opencvpluginsample.kmd.json**.Also i downloaded  the latest gstreamer using the command **wget http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gstreamer/gstreamer-1.7.90.tar.xz**.
Used  **./config** and **sudo make install** 
   But when i run the cmakelist using cmake-gui
      It shows the error"checking for module 'gstreamer-video1.0>=1.3.3' not found"
      When i searched in gstreamer,the module video is missing.I tried to install seperately,but i am unable to do it.
   How can i solve this?

Comment: Now the repository is updated([link](https://github.com/Kurento/kms-opencv-plugin-sample)) and it successfully generated the libkmsopencvpluginsampleimpl.so.I have to run my opencv project using kurento,What i have to do next?

Comment: You need to create an application that uses this filter. But seems like a different question, because this project only contains an example plugin, not an application that uses it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply
I need to run the opencv application using kurento.i do not understand the flow.It will be helpful for me if u provide me with any documentation or links regarding the flow

Comment: http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/stable/mastering/kurento_modules.html  You can start reading kurento docs about plugins and the the page about creating your own modules http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/stable/mastering/develop_kurento_modules.html Maybe this can help you to understand the process.

Comment: ,i have few doubts regarding the opencv implementation with kerento,can i have your mail id pls?

Comment: Sorry I can't give you that. If you have specific questions about kurento try contact kurento team at info@kurento.org.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106200/discussion-between-cibin-william-and-santoscadenas).

Comment: If you get a chance,please join this room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/36966/kurento-media-server